# Parallel builds in Maven in JVM

Tags: maven, maven-3

My understanding about parallel builds in Maven, after going through following link, is as follows:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3

When Maven performs parallel builds for independent sub modules, each module is built in its own JVM. For example: If there are 2 modules M1 and M2 which can be built in parallel then each module will be built in its own JVM.

Is above understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is 1 JVM with multiple threads. This also explains the `-T` argument:

```
-T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                       where C is core multiplied
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although each module is executed by different thread but i was thinking that thread will internally be spawning a new JVM process to do maven build.